# why my component didn't re-render when the state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, state, jsx

---

the values of value 1 and 2 and 3 which stored in the props are Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) so what I want to know when I setState and the value of numQuestions , numCorrect  change and the render method is being called as I know why this render didn't make the three values 1,2,3 reproduced again and their values change with each click of the two buttons .

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.proposedAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + this.props.value1 + this.props.value2 + this.props.value3;
      this.state = {
        numQuestions : 0,
        numCorrect : 0,
      }
   }

   rightanswer= ()=> {
        if(this.proposedAnswer === this.props.value1 + this.props.value2 + this.props.value3){
          this.setState((oldstate)=> ({
            numCorrect : oldstate.numCorrect +=1 ,
            numQuestions : oldstate.numQuestions += 1 ,
          }))
        }else{
             this.setState((oldstate)=> ({
             numQuestions : oldstate.numQuestions += 1 ,
         }))
     }
  }

   falseanswer= ()=> {
         if(this.proposedAnswer !== this.props.value1 + this.props.value2 + this.props.value3){
           this.setState((oldstate)=> ({
               numCorrect : oldstate.numCorrect +=1 ,
               numQuestions : oldstate.numQuestions += 1 ,
           }))
         }else{
               this.setState((oldstate)=> ({
               numQuestions : oldstate.numQuestions += 1 ,
         }))
        }
      }

   render() {
      return (
          <div className="App">
            <div className="game">
              <h2>Mental Math</h2>
              <div className="equation">
                  <p className="text">{`${this.props.value1} + ${this.props.value2} + 
                   ${this.props.value3} = ${this.proposedAnswer}`}</p>
              </div>
              <button  onClick={() => this.rightanswer()}>True</button>
              <button onClick={() => this.falseanswer()}>False</button>
              <p className="text">
                 Your Score: {this.state.numCorrect}/{this.state.numQuestions}
              </p>
             </div>
          </div>
       );
      }
    }

  export default App;
```

Comment: You are trying to add, so use `+` instead of `+=`

Comment: You'll probably also need to bind the class functions to the class context. In the constructor `this.rightanswer = this.rightanswer.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is re-rendering when the state changes. However, your props do not change because you are not passing in new props from the parent component, so `value1`, `value2`, and `value3` remain the same.

If you want your `value`s to change on a state change, one approach is to move all of your `value`s to state, initialize them when the component mounts, and update them when your component updates:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numQuestions: 0,
      numCorrect: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.generateValues();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.numQuestions !== prevState.numQuestions) {
      this.generateValues();
    }
  }

  generateValues = () => {
    const values = [...Array(3)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    const correctAnswer = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    const proposedAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + correctAnswer;
    this.setState({
      value1: values[0],
      value2: values[1],
      value3: values[2],
      correctAnswer: correctAnswer,
      proposedAnswer: proposedAnswer
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your help ,You taught me a lot of things that I didn't know 
I did what you explained ,but the values also after each click didn't change

Comment: Can you edit your post with your current approach? This code works for me

Comment: it is working now thank you ,It was my fault I was using =+ 1 in the function instead of + 1

Comment: but I didn't know what is the difference that make the problem occur where the numbers of the numQuestions,numCorrect were changing on the screen but the generation of the values didn't occur

Comment: The `value`s are passed in as props from a parent component that you haven't shown. You never make any updates to these prop values, so they stay the same even if the state changes in the child component and the child component re-renders

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions don't have a `this` binding (more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). You're also calling them on the `onClick` of the `button` with `this.falseanswer`. So the class can't find the binding and hence the function returns nothing cause it's like it doesn't exist. Additionally when we pass functions to event handlers and the functions have no arguments the best practice is to just pass the function like this: `onClick={myFunciton}`.

So in your case I'd turn these arrow functions into methods, bind them at the `constructor` and call them on the `onClick` event

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.proposedAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + this.props.value1 + this.props.value2 + this.props.value3;
      this.state = {
        numQuestions : 0,
        numCorrect : 0,
      }
      this.falseAnswer = this.falseAnswer.bind(this);
   }

  falseAnswer () { ...}

  render () {
   return (
   <button onClick={this.falseAnswer}>False</button>
   );
  }
```

Comment: but the function is working and the values of numQuestions and numCorrect are increasing onclick and display on the page